# Disable window vertical stretch (and only that)

Tags: windows-8, resizing

There's an annoying feature in windows 8 that when you resize a window and try to stretch the bottom of it to the bottom of the desktop, it automatically stretches the top to the top as well.

Is there a way to turn this off?

[image]

But I don't wanna lose any other features like when you move the window to the top it maximizes, and when you move it to the left it resizes to half the desktop size, etc. Just wanna turn this specific feature off.

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to turn just that feature off. What you can do, though, is work around it by moving the window to the bottom of the screen, and then resizing from the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this in [Winaero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/blog/disable-snapping-in-windows-10-but-keep-other-extended-window-management-options)! It has an option to specifically "disable vertical maximizing of windows".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i'm not using win8 so i dont know the exact solution, but you can try this: a similar feature was in win7 and could be changed via control panel > accessibility > mouse settings > "prevent windows from resizing when moved to the screen edge" (or something like that).. check that area, maybe you'll find an option there.

EDIT: nevermind, i missed the part where you mentioned you didnt wanna lose the other functionality.. sorry.